# How to substract string from a string array

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have a `String[8] a`, and its elements are

```
a[0] = "08:00:00";
a[1] = "09:00:00";
...
a[8] = "16:00:00";
```

And I want all the `a` elements to be less, like

```
a[0] = "08:00";
a[1] = "09:00";
...
a[8] = "16:00";
```

Maybe this is an idiot question, but how could I make/do that in java (exactly android)?

Comment: `for (int i=0;i<a.length;i++)a[i]=a[i].substring(0,5);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, for this exact task you can use regular expression to remove the last part:

```
a[i] = a[i].replaceAll(":\\d+$", "");
```

Or, if you're sure about the format (and zeros):

```
a[i] = a[i].substring(0, 5);
```

But why you can't create the array itself with the loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
    a[i] = String.format("%02d:00", i + 8);
}
```